# How to Split Strings in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

**Firstly, I know that there may be a duplicate but I do not understand them, so please don't mark this as a duplicate!**

I wish to split the strings in an array (see below) into characters:

Original:

```
String original = "0, 0, 0, 0 | 1, 1, 1, 1 | 2, 2, 2, 2"
```

Array:

```
String[] array2 = {"0, 0, 0, 0", "1, 1, 1, 1", "2, 2, 2, 2"}
```

Result that I want:

```
String[] arrayprime = {"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2"}
```

How would you do this? I thought of

```
String[] array2 = original.split("\\|");
String[] arrayprime = array2.split(", ");
```

but it doesn't seem to work (says "Cannot find symbol").

Should I make the array (array2) into a String (if so, how)? And then split again?

Comment: `array2.split(", ");`?

Comment: Wouldn't your second split be set to work on commas? You seem to have it on a space

Comment: You can split on multiple delimiters in one call.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the edit - fixed! I'll look into it.

Comment: I posted the link.

Comment: That worked - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to split on `", "` OR `" | "`.

Since `split` supports regular expression you can write it as

```
String[] array = yourText.split(", | \\| ");
//                                 ^-OR operator which creates 
//                                   alternation between ", " and " | "
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`character classes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) which required no escaping in this case

```
    String original = "0, 0, 0, 0 | 1, 1, 1, 1 | 2, 2, 2, 2";
    String arr[]=original.split("[|,]");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line

```
String[] arrayprime = array2.split(" ");
```

You cannot use split method on array. Split method is on String. So basically you have to iterate over `array2` and apply split on each `String`.

Or simply use regex

```
String[] array2 = original.split("\\||,");
```

Note that you'll have spaces in your Strings after using this as your initial string have spaces. Please consider trimming them to get desired output.